# Issue with cx_Oracle, where can I download cx_Oracle.pyd

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

From where can I download the file cx_Oracle.pyd for Python 3.5?

I am having issues while installing cx_Oracle on my Windows7 Machine

I dont have registry edit permission on my machine, so it seems that when I installed Python 3.5 its entry was not made in the registry. Therefore when I run cx_Oracle installer on windows then it complains that it could not find the Python 3.5 entry in the registry.

I tried to build cx_Oracle form source it goves the below error

creating build\temp.win32-3.5-12c\Release
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\oracle\instantclient_12_1\sdk\include -Ic:\users\\appdata\local
\programs\python\python35-32\include -Ic:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include /Tccx_Oracle.c /
Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5-12c\Release\cx_Oracle.obj -DBUILD_VERSION=5.2.1
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

So I think I am only left with the option of placing the file cx_Oracle.pyd  in Python path. But I could not locate it in the web, any pointer where can I get this file directly would be helpful.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0):

The installers found on PyPI (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle) are simply zip files appended to a stub executable. So you can simply extract the files directly from the zip file and place them in the Python path directly if you would like. Note that you do need to make sure that if you are running a 64-bit Python that you also install a 64-bit cx_Oracle and if you are running a 32-bit Python that you also install a 32-bit cx_Oracle.

Building cx_Oracle from source on Windows requires a C compiler. The default is Visual Studio 2015 but you can also use gcc from the mingw32 package.